# How to set timeout react-native api call using fetch(GET Call)?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, networking, fetch

This my code(used to fetch data).

```
loadApi() {
    this.setState({isListLoaded : true})
    return fetch('http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt')
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((responseJson) => {
         this.setState({listView : responseJson.worldpopulation})
         this.setState({isListLoaded : false})
         ToastAndroid.show('A pikachu appeared nearby !', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
       });
  }
```

How can i set a timeout to this specific syntax ?.Please share the code part if you have any.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way till now according to [this github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2556) thread.

However there is one solution, use [whatwg-fetch-timeout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch-timeout)

sample code :

```
return fetch('/path', {timeout: 500}).then(function() {
    // successful fetch 
}).catch(function(error) {
   // network request failed / timeout 
})
```